# Why $index is zero if object has index 1?

Tags: angularjs

I have object `data.specialization.all`:

```
{"1":{"name":"Ailə","checked":false,"id":"6"}}
```

And `ng-repeat`:

```
ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.specialization.all | orderObjectBy : 'value.name' : true"
```

Inside `ng-repeat` I display `key`:

```
{{key}}
```

And get zero (0)

Why if I have index 1 in object?

Comment: what does orderObjectBy do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your filter:

> orderObjectBy : 'value.name' : true"

Basically, the return of that is an enumerable list instead of a dictionary. You're getting the index of the first element of that list, not the key to your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This jsbin shows the correct key.

http://jsbin.com/mirisixodo/edit?html,js,output

The issue appears to be in your filter. Could you post that code?